# JavaMail - AuthenticationFailedException while reading outlook mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm using below code to read outlook email using Java mail 1.6.2

```
          Properties props = new Properties();        
          props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");     
          Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props); 
          mailSession.setDebug(true);
          Store mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imap");
          mailStore.connect("outlook.office365.com", "abc@company.com", "password");
```

However i'm getting below error even though login credentials are proper. Please find the logs below :

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBBADEAsomeText]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=abc@company.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: That's probably Microsoft's risk assessment. They try to guess whether your client is the bona-fide user or a nasty bot. FYI, you might solve it by migrating off PLAIN altogether: [Microsoft will disable plain authentication in a few months](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers) so you'll have to do it anyway later this year.

Comment: @arnt Can you please provide code snippet or working example ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. While I have used both javamail and office365, I've never used those two together.

Comment: @Bill Shannon any solution ?

Comment: You might be running into the bug where the server says it supports PLAIN authentication but it really doesn't.  See [this Mail project page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/Exchange).

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for the reply. As per the link you shared I tried “mail.imap.auth.plain.disable” to “true” which gave javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246) 
And for 2nd option , i didn't understand "Disabling all authentication types and falling back to IMAP LOGIN support seemed to work." I tried "mail.imap.auth.disable", "true" and got javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

Comment: @BillShannon Update to above comment :  I didn't understand "Disabling all authentication types and falling back to IMAP LOGIN support seemed to work." However i tried : props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
   props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
   props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
   props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable", "true");

with props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); and still getting the same error.

Comment: Of course you're getting the error, you've disabled all the supported authentication mechanisms!  The server only supports PLAIN and XOAUTH2.  Ideally, PLAIN should work, perhaps you're not really using the correct user name or password.  Can you configure Thunderbird to connect to the same account?  (Just as another data point while debugging.)  Can you use the same credentials with their web user interface?  If you end up having to use XOAUTH2, its going to be much more difficult.  You should check with your server administrator to see what's expected.

Comment: @BillShannon I'm able to login to this account using thunderbird with the same credentials. Not sure why PLAIN isn't working.

Comment: @BillShannon problem was host ! replaced outlook.office365.com (imap-mail.outlook.com) to company specific host and it worked !  mailStore.connect("mail.ad.company.com", "abc@company.com", "password"); Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Did Thunderbird work without the company-specific host?

Comment: @BillShannon for thunderbird i didn't give host details. It prompted me to enter just username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was wrong host ! replaced outlook.office365.com (imap-mail.outlook.com) to company specific host and it worked !

```
mailStore.connect("mail.ad.company.com", "abc@company.com", "password");
```

Comment: How did you find the company-specific host? I have a tenant on Azure and my mail ID looks like user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com. I am unable to figure out the company-specific host for this. Please help.

Comment: I got it from IT team. They only had created the new email ID that I used in my java application.